# 2 video files, one has the audio with 15FPS, the other has the video with 5FPS, audio is out of sync

Tags: audio, framerate, sync, handbrake

I'm trying to sync the audio and video of 2 different files, one is a 15 FPS webcam stream with audio and the other is a screen share with 5 FPS. This is an educational setting.

I'm trying to do the math in my head on what causes the audio desync, is it the 10FPS difference?

I first extracted the audio from the webcam mp4 and inserted it into the video using mkvmerge, then used handbrake to encode it in constant fps and it didn't work. I tried 5, 15 and 30 fps in handbrake.

The question is, is there a way I can sync these by messing with FPS or some other property, or d I need to manually determine how desynced the audio is and manually shift it?

Comment: To repeat the answer, when files are recorded independently, they will almost always have sync issues. A full video editor is really the only solution if you must have perfect sync. In the future, an application that records both files and accounts for syncing along the way will save you this headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two devices that recorded the videos weren't synchronised together, so their clocks will drift over time.  There's no way to guarantee perfect synchronisation, but if you have audio recorded on both, you could use something like [Premiere's multi-cam workflow](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/create-multi-camera-source-sequence.html) to sync the footage.  If it drifts, you'll have to do some manual editing and recutting to get it back into sync.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't thought of it that way.